# Powerbuilder 7.0 - Pass value from an event to another event

Tags: event-handling, powerbuilder

i'm currently using Powerbuilder 7.0. So i got an object that need to modify 2 events. It is an inventory program, which will check if the item are below the level, it will pop out a message to show current available qty and reorder level qty.

So event **stock_reorder_level** are for displaying the message, and event **stock_checking** are for the checking of stock qty. Now i've done the message, but it shows 0 for available and reorder qty. The value for the qty are defined on event **stock_checking**, i wasn't sure how to pass the value of qty to the **stock_reorder_level** event. Below are some of the coding i've done.

[event stock_reorder_level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylsy4.jpg)

[event stock_checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ99h.jpg)

My question: how to pass dec_totPrdQty and dec_stockReorderLevel to event stock_reorder_level.

Comment: I do not understand what is your problem ?, to the events adds as many arguments as you need and passes the value where it corresponds when you make the call of the event.

Comment: I need to point the dec_totPrdQty and dec_stockReorderLevel to the other event.

Comment: I wonder why you use events instead of functions.  it practically amounts to the same, except events can be triggered by specific elements (click, right-click,...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Add `adec_prdqty` and `adec_reorderlevel` as parameters to the event definition for `stock_reorder_level` instead of the two local variables.
- pass the two values as arguments when you call `stock_reorder_level`. EX:

  ```
  THIS.EVENT ue_reachStockReorderLevel(al_row, dec_totPrdQty, dec_stockReorderLevel)
  ```

You toggle the event definition in PowerBuilder's script painter with the button "Show/Hide Prototype" located in the top right-hand corner.

Comment: Pass by should be 'value' or 'reference'?

Comment: 'Value' passes a duplicate of the variable, 'reference' passes a pointer to the variable.  You only need to use by reference if you plan on working with the variable within the first event after the return from the second event.

Comment: After done passing the the argument from event stock_checking, do i need to declare it on the event stock_reorder_level?